# Why can I only connect to myself through socket? (python)

Tags: python, sockets, client, server

I'm trying to make simple Client-Server program but it's only working when I'm running both scripts on same computer, when moving it to other computer - It does not make connection at all.

Server:

```
__author__ = 'user-pc'
import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host="0.0.0.0"              # Bind with everyone
port = 13254                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port

s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
   print 'Got connection from', addr
   c.send('Thank you for connecting')
   c.close()                # Close the connection
```

Client:

```
__author__ = 'user-pc'
import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = "192.168.10.4"       # Server Ip
port = 13254                # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
print s.recv(1024)
s.close                     # Close the socket when done
```

Can you please help me to figure the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Is the port of the server open for the client? `iptables`, `firewalls` and such...

Comment: Do a google search on "how to open a port on <your server OS>?"

Comment: Is your server and client in the same network? How are they connected to the network? Before running ur programm try to ping the server from client to ensure that you have the connectivity to the server. If you get reply then it is not a network problem. Run ur program now, then try to ping the port 13254, if you don't get a reply then it could be the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

As it works when you run both scripts on the server it is likely your port is closed.

Verify your port is open. Go to this website: http://www.canyouseeme.org/

Enter your port and IP. It is highly likely your port is closed. This will verify that. Assuming your port is open you need to look into your firewall settings as reccomended by dmg in the comment above. Then, it is no longer a python issue!

Comment: Does the port need to be open on both computers? or only the server

Comment: both. but I suspect it is more likely that the server port is closed than the client port.